# Mortar or tile adhesive? For 9”x9” tub surround wall tiles

Tags: tile

Would a tile adhesive or mortar be better for mounting shower wall tiles (9” x9” porcelain)?

Comment: what is the wall made of?

Answer (score 0):

For long lasting results you want to use thinset mortar on backer board.

Or you need to find a solvent based tile adhesive.  The newer low VOC water based ones don't stand up in wet environments.  The older solvent based ones can  hold up for at lest 13 years in a 2 shower a day environment on a drywall backing.  (I did it.  Installed 1" tiles, grouted same when I was 14.  Mom had the bathroom redone when I was in my late 20's)